# Convert List of Dictionaries to nested list of dictionaries (with duplicate values merged)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

With a list of dictionaries, I want to create a nested dictionary of lists.

Example data:

```
 data = [ { 'State': 'IL', 'City': 'Chicago', 'Schools': [ 'school_a', 'school_b' ] },
          { 'State': 'IL', 'City': 'Chicago', 'Schools': [ 'school_c', 'school_d' ] },
          { 'State': 'IL', 'City': 'Evanston', 'Schools': [ 'school_x', 'school_y' ] }]
```

Desired output data:

```
new_data = { 'IL' : [ 'Chicago'  : { 'Schools': ['school_a', 'school_b', 'school_c', 'school_d'] },
                      'Evanston' : { 'Schools : ['school_x', 'school_y'] } ] }
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

---> Edits below:

@Samwise's solution below worked great for the above example.

What if we made Schools into a hash as well want to create something like this below:

How can we go about doing this?

```
#Example data:

 data = [ { 'State': 'IL', 'City': 'Chicago', 'Schools': { 'high' : 'school_a', 'midddle' : 'school_b' } },
          { 'State': 'IL', 'City': 'Chicago', 'Schools': { 'high' : 'school_c', 'middle' :'school_d' } },
          { 'State': 'IL', 'City': 'Evanston', 'Schools': { 'high' :'school_x', 'middle' : 'school_y' } }]

#Desired output data:

new_data = { 'IL' : [ 'Chicago'  : [ { 'Schools': {'high': 'school_a', 'middle': 'school_b'} },
                                    { 'Schools': {'high': 'school_c', 'middle': 'school_d'} } ],
                     'Evanston' : { 'Schools : {'high': 'school_x', 'middle': 'school_y'} } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `defaultdict` to make it easy to add elements to the dictionary as you iterate through the original `data`:

```
>>> new_data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {'Schools': []}))
>>> for row in data:
...     new_data[row['State']][row['City']]['Schools'].extend(row['Schools'])
```

Comment: Thanks, @Samwise :D I've edited the post with a follow-up question. do you have any suggestions/recommendations on the new question?  Thank you!!

Comment: If you understand the answer to the first question it should be easy to apply the same approach to the second question.  :)

Comment: so I tried "new_data = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(lambda: { 'data': collections.defaultdict(dict)}))" But in this case, First Chicago was getting overwritten by the second Chicago I guess a more appropriate question is the following: is there a way to not know the uniqueness of key and dynamically make the structure into list? Or do you need to know this upfront at the structure declaration? (do I just have to make everything list of dictionires in this case?) –

Comment: If you know the structure of `data` when you're writing your code, then it's straightforward to build a nested `defaultdict` that has the same structure so that you can just insert entries into it as a single operation.  It's possible to figure it out at runtime, but that's a different (and harder) problem -- you need to traverse it using `isinstance` to figure out if each element is a dictionary, list, or scalar, and then conditionally build up `new_data` piece by piece to match.  Doable, but makes it much more than three lines of code!